# Синоним "нежели"

Tags: синонимы

Я всегда думал что *нежели* можно заменить на *чем*, но видимо это не так.

Придумайте что можно вставить вместо знаков вопроса, чтобы сохранился исходный смысл предложения:

> Я другой нежели он. Я другой ??? он.

Я другой чем он. -- Это ошибка или нет? Получается что "нежели" - незаменим?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Я другой нежели он. Я другой ??? он.

Если написать по правилам, с запятой: ***"Я другой, чем он"***, то это не ошибка. Во всяком случае - не грамматическая ошибка, такое встречается сплошь и рядом. 
Более того, словари зачастую приводят единственное значение для "нежели", определяя его как синонимичное "чем", что предполагает возможность рассматриваемой замены ***во всех случаях***.

> Подлиповцы узнали здесь больше, нежели они знали в деревне и в
>   Чердыни: они узнали, что миру божьему нет конца, что деревни их дрянь,
>   люди совсем другие, чем они, что им уж не быть такими, какие ходят в
>   городе в богатой одежде. [Ф. М. Решетников. Подлиповцы (1864)]

..-

> Теперь сравнительно редко найдешь актера, который сумел бы воссоздать
>   совсем другого, чем он сам, человека. [Анатолий Эфрос. Профессия: режиссер 
>   (1975-1987)]

Примеры для убедительности из совершенно разных эпох (взяты из нацкорпуса). 
А ощущение ошибочности, видимо, стоит отнести на счет непривычности использования "чем" в сравнительном обороте без наречия или прилагательного сравнительной степени (более часто встречается вариант типа "Петя умнее, чем Вася", "Вася бежал быстрее, чем Петя). 
Согласен, что в общей массе случаев использования союза "чем", конструкция, подобная рассматриваемой, - дело нечастое, но совершенно непонятно, зачем и на что её заменять.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант: "Я другой, не такой, как он".
Еще одним синонимом является - "в сравнении" либо "по сравнению".
Я другой по сравнению с ним.